# Why left-shift in JS and Dart are different?

Tags: javascript, dart, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

In Javascript:
`255 << 24 = -16777216`

In dart:
`255 << 24 = 4278190080`

Is there any way by which I get the same answer in Dart similar to JS ?

Comment: Comparing different languages with different behavior is difficult, and sometimes impossible. Why do you expect JavaScript and Dart to have the same behavior?

Answer (score 2):

To get precisely the same result in Dart as in JavaScript (whether on the web or not), do:

```dart
  var jsValue = (255 << 24).toSigned(32);
```

JavaScript converts all bitwise operations to 32-bit integers, and to signed integers for all operators except `>>>`.
So, do `.toSigned(32)` on the result to do precisely what `JavaScript` does.